# Convert Makefile to Bazel?

Tags: makefile, xgboost, bazel

Bazel says that best practice is to not use binary dependencies, [but to build the dependency from source using Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/best-practices.html#depending-on-binaries). I have a dependency - [xgboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) - that builds using Makefiles, and I was wondering what the canonical strategy is to convert Makefiles to Bazel - as well as if there are any standard tools that programmers use as part of the conversion.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "canonical way" to do it right now. The easiest way is probably to just shell out to make in a non-hermetic generule and declare the needed output of the rule, e.g.:

```
genrule(
   name = "xgboost",
   srcs = glob(["xgboost/**"]),
   cmd = "\n".join([
         "DIR=$$(mktemp -d $${TMPDIR-/tmp}/tmp.XXXXXXX)",
         "(cd $(execution_root)/xgboost && cp -fr . \"$${DIR}\")",
         "(cd \"$${DIR}\" && make target)",
         "cp $${DIR}/output $@",
         ]),
   outs = ["xgboost-output"],
   local = 1,
)
```

Of course, `target`, `output` and `xgboost-output` are to be replaced by what works for you.